# Cannot load page on Firefox, Safari, IE (Polymer) - webcomponents.js error

Tags: html, firefox, polymer, web-component, paper-elements

I was building a page, and got into a problem which I was struggling with for awhile. The source code is here: https://gist.github.com/zafartahirov/077b3e9ca7fe9958c9e1 - sorry it's not on JSbin, I still cannot figure out how to use multiple files there.

The page works fine on Chrome, but gives me an error Firefox: `TypeError: value is not a non-null object` in `webcomponents.js` and `Exception caught during observer callback: destributeNodeInto...` in `polymer.js`.

The page is running on http://zafar.cc - but I am expecting to push a different version there once this problem is fixed. The GitHub repo for the page is here: https://github.com/zafartahirov/zafar.cc

Please, advise... :)

EDIT: The live example of the errors could be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/zafartahirov/raw/077b3e9ca7fe9958c9e1/ - sorry about importing `element/...` - forgot to change it in the `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `elements/zaf-dropdown/zaf-dropdown.html:16` you have:

```
<shadow></shadow>
```

I bet you want to replace it with

```
<content></content>
```

or even simply drop it. This change fixes the behaviour in browsers not having native support for webcomponents yet.

**P. S.** IMHO, this is not a best idea to stole the design from polymer paper-elements project.

Comment: You are right in saying that the `<shadow></shadow>` was the problem - getting rid of it solves the problem.

About "stealing" - what do you mean I stole it? The license is there, the reference to the original website is there, this is a personal, non-commercial project - I fail to see how is it "stealing". It's a BSD license - free to use and modify...

Comment: @RafazZ Oh, sorry, I did not mean you to take my P.S. so personal. I mean, changing colors and/or logo would make your site more attractive :)

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong - I am genuinely asking if I am violating any licensing. I will change the logos and colors once I fix all the bugs, I just don't want the actual developers feel like I am not giving them credit. Thank you for the answer - it helped me a lot. Quick question - is it possible to include `<shadow>` conditionally, depending on the browser being used?

Comment: I have no connection to polymer’s developers. I just dropped a note that your great site might be more “personal” whether you change a color. Just a rare glance of a stranger, not more :) Relative to your last question: why do you ever want to use `<shadow>`?